# RuntimeError: unable to open shared memory object, OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files

Tags: python, memory, pytorch

I having trouble with loading indexes of document.
I am testing my code, so I set

```
batch_size = 4
number_of_sentences_in_document = 84
number_of_words_in_sentence = 80
```

that sums up one mini_batch with `80 * 84 * 4` indexes of documents.

The problem is that when I transform those indexes dataset into a DataLoader as below
and try to loop over trainloader, it results out so many error messages.

```
DataManager = DS.NewsDataset(data_examples_gen, Vocab)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(DataManager, batch_size=Args.args.batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=32)
```

The error messages are below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 61, in _worker_loop
    data_queue.put((idx, samples))   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 341, in put   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/reductions.py", line 125, in reduce_storage   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 191, in DupFd   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/resource_sharer.py", line 48, in __init__ OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/util.py", line 262, in _run_finalizers   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/util.py", line 186, in __call__   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 476, in rmtree   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 474, in rmtree OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '/tmp/pymp-be4nmgxw' Process Process-2: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 61, in _worker_loop
    data_queue.put((idx, samples))   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 341, in put   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/reductions.py", line 125, in reduce_storage   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 191, in DupFd   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/resource_sharer.py", line 48, in __init__ OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 61, in _worker_loop
    data_queue.put((idx, samples))   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 341, in put   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/reductions.py", line 121, in reduce_storage RuntimeError: unable to open shared memory object </torch_54415_3383444026> in read-write mode at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1525909934016/work/aten/src/TH/THAllocator.c:342
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/util.py", line 262, in _run_finalizers   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/util.py", line 186, in __call__   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 476, in rmtree   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 474, in rmtree OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '/tmp/pymp-abguy87b' Process Process-1: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 61, in _worker_loop
    data_queue.put((idx, samples))   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 341, in put   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/reductions.py", line 121, in reduce_storage RuntimeError: unable to open shared memory object </torch_54415_3383444026> in read-write mode at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1525909934016/work/aten/src/TH/THAllocator.c:342 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/nlpgpu3/LinoHong/FakeNewsByTitle/main.py", line 26, in <module>
    for mini_batch in trainloader :   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 280, in __next__
    idx, batch = self._get_batch()   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 259, in _get_batch
    return self.data_queue.get()   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 335, in get
    res = self._reader.recv_bytes()   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 216, in recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv_bytes(maxlength)   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 407, in _recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv(4)   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 379, in _recv
    chunk = read(handle, remaining)   File "/home/nlpgpu3/anaconda3/envs/linohong3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 178, in handler
    _error_if_any_worker_fails() RuntimeError: DataLoader worker (pid 54416) exited unexpectedly with exit code 1.
```

Process finished with exit code 1

I thought this is some kind of memory problem so I tried the same thing
only having two sentences for a document and it worked.
However, I am expecting this to get pretty much larger with
batch_size up to 32 or 64,
the number of sentences per document up to 84
the number of words per sentence up to 84.

I tried

```
$ ulimit -n 10000
```

but that one didn't work.

How can I manage this problem?
Any Idea???

Comment: [related](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/539)?

Comment: I'm sorry, could you be more specific??